# Responsive jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

The below script I am using is currently working when it comes to calling the jQuery when it hits a specific screen size. However, my `window.onmousemove` event is no longer working. When you hover over `#hwdo-panel ul li` the div `.show-info` will follow my cursor within the div. But when I add `if ($(window).width() < 992){` to the script the div no longer follows my cursor. When I am trying to achieve is on screens higher then 992 call the `window.onmousemove` script and anything lower then 992 display `.show-info` on its own. What am I doing wrong with my below script?

```
if ($(window).width() < 992){
  $('#hwdo-panel ul li').hover(function(e){
   var figure = $(this).find('.show-info');
    if(figure){
        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var x = e.pageX,
                  y = e.pageY;
            figure.offset({ top: (y + 0), left: (x + 50)});
        }
    }
 });
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
     <li>
           <h3>Details</h3>
           <p>this is a test</p>
      </li>
      <li>
            <h3>Passion</h3>
           <p>this is a test</p>
      </li>
      <li>
            <h3>Courage</h3>
           <p>this is a test</p>
      </li>
      <li>
            <h3>Care</h3>
           <p>this is a test</p>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
 #hwdo-panel {
     position: relative;

ul {
    font-weight: 900;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;     
    
    &:hover > li {
        opacity:0.1;
    }
    
    li {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        -webkit-transition:0.5s;
                      transition:0.5s;
    
        &:hover{
            opacity:1;
        }

        &:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        &:hover .show-info {
            display: block;
        }   

        .show-info {
            display: block;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: relative;
            padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
            font-weight: 500;
            width: 100%;
            
            @media (min-width:992px) {
                display: none;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                background: var(--pink);
                padding: 2em;
                font-weight: 500;
                width: 30%;
                z-index: 90;
            }
        }

        h3 {
            position: relative;
            color: transparent;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
            -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;

            &:before {
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 0;
                color: var(--pink);
                content: attr(data-hover);
            }

            &:hover:before {
                width: 100%;     
                transition: all 3s cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.32, 0.87);
            }

            &:after {
                content: '+';
                position: relative;
                float: right;
                font-size: .5em;
                color: var(--white);
                -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
                -webkit-text-stroke-color: transparent;
                font-weight: 500;
            }
            &:hover:after {
                color: var(--pink);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/skaz41w0/1/)

Comment: 1) To diagnose DOM/responsive issues it helps ***a lot*** to have all the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JS etc) in a working snippet. 2) `if (figure)` will always be true. You need `if (figure.length)` instead. 3) Nested event handlers is almost always a bad idea. I'm sure there's a better way to do what you need, but point 1) is required first.

Comment: Use jQuery to attach the `mousemove` event to `window` (e.g., `$(window).on('mousemove', function () { ... })`. Then, inside of that function check the status of the window width and/or display of divs. You should be controlling the display of the div using CSS and checking its visibility using jQuery's `:visible` selector.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I uploaded all my information and included my example. I do agree with you about nested event handlers. I have been trying to come up with a different solution but cant seem to come up with a solution

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're only instantiating the hover handler if the window starts out at the right size, it won't update if the window resizes.  And the nested handlers means you're instantiating a new mousemove handler every time the hover state changes.

Instead, you can leave a single mousemove handler running all the time, and check the window size inside it.  Conveniently the hover state can be detected using CSS selectors, so you can skip needing to worry about specifically watching the hover events.

This is untested but should be close:

```
window.onmousemove = e => {
  // handle your window size check inside the mousemove handler:
  if ($(window).width() > 991) return;

  // use a CSS selector to detect the hover state:
  let figure = $('#hwdo-panel ul li:hover .show-info');

  // now do your positioning
  if (figure) {
    figure[0].offset({
      top: e.pageY,
      left: e.pageX
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try something like this and your code but I keep running into the same issue the div no longer follows my cursor. For some reason when I add anything related to a window size it disables the figure[0].offset

Comment: That would be a very surprising result.